# Why doesn't my PHP delete button work?

Tags: php, mysql, button, html-table, sql-delete

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to create a table which has a delete button/link beside each row, when clicked deletes that row.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ca229');

mysql_select_db('testdb');

$result = mysql_query('select * from products');

$numrows = mysql_numrows($result);

//****************************************************************
print "<table border = 3 style = width:400px>";


for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    print "<tr>";


    foreach($row as $cell)
    {

        print "<td>";
        print $cell;
        print "</td>";



    }
      print "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row["id"] ."' >Delete</a> " ;


    print "</tr>";


}


print "</table>";
//***************************************************************   

mysql_close();

?>
```

and...

```
<?php

$id = $_GET["id"];
$delete = " DELETE * from products where id = ". $id ;

mysql_query($delete) ; 

?>
```

Comment: Try and put your delete `<a href='delete.php?id=".$row["id"] ."' >Delete</a>` inside your `foreach($row as $cell)` loop. Plus, as stated below, remove the `*` after `DELETE`

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What exactly happens?

Comment: If this is an application on the public internet I'd be more concerned about the **gigantic** [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) you have there due to a completely reckless disregard for [proper escaping practices](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please do not write new code with `mysql_query` because it's woefully out of date and being removed from PHP in the near future.

Comment: I'm assuming that upon clicking your link, the responding PHP document re-connects to the database??  What kind of error message are you getting?  Beyond that, I would stray away from mysql_* functions.  Look into mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Looks like `delete.php` doesn't open a database connection. Other things: you're using `mysql_*()` which is deprecated - use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO`; you're not escaping the `$_GET` variable used in your `DELETE` query so it's open to SQL injection. Look at prepared statements.

Comment: How does this code create a button?

Comment: This is the error message: Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/table.php on line 38 Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/table.php on line 38 Notice: Undefined index: id in /var/www/table.php on line 38

Comment: Typo `$numrows = mysql_numrows($result);` change to `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);`

Comment: You really would have a better time getting your application working if you picked a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that fit your style and needs, then followed along with examples for that platform. It looks like you're just throwing code at the wall and hoping it runs based on the numerous mistakes you've made here. Learning PHP from the absolute bottom up is very challenging and will be a lot harder than starting from the top down.

Comment: Then try `print "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$cell["id"] ."' >Delete</a> ";` since you have `$row as $cell`

Comment: Just read my answer. It's got all the fixes you need.

Comment: Your delete file doesn't have any SQL DB/connection stuff in there also.

Comment: So, any luck so far? @user3464531

Answer (score 1):

add database connection lines in beginning of delete.php file.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ca229');
mysql_select_db('testdb');
```

You need to open connection for mysql_query to work on your database.

Answer (score 1):

Before we go on with the good stuff, let me first point out where the original errors were made.

Since `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);` creates an enumerated array (ex: array(0=>'value1', 1=>'value2', ...)), not an associative array, `$row["id"]` will be undefined. This will still generate HTML but all your delete buttons will have no id specified.

This line:

```
$delete = "DELETE * from products where id = ". $id;
```

You don't need the `*` just do:

```
$delete = "DELETE from products where id = ". $id;
```

---

(*Now, the good stuff*) --- By the way, I used `id` - `product` - `city` as column examples.

Here is an `mysqli_*` version. Replace `xxx` with your DB credentials.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$db = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$results = mysqli_query($db,"select * from products");

print "<table border=1 cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\">\n";

echo "<tr>\n";
echo '<td width="25%">
      <p align="center">ID</td>
    <td width="25%">
      <p align="center">PRODUCT</td>
    <td width="25%">
      <p align="center">CITY</td>
    <td width="25%">
      <p align="center">ACTION</td>
  </tr>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {

    print "<tr><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>\n<td>" . $row['product'] . "</td>\n" . "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>\n" . "<td>\n"  . "<a href='delete.php?id=".$row["id"] ."'>Delete</a>\n</td>\n</tr>\n";

}

print "</table>\n";

echo "<hr>"; // simply a seperator. You can delete this

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

---

Delete code - `mysqli_*` (delete.php)

```
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xxx');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) 
OR die("could not connect");

$id = (int)$_GET["id"];

$delete = "DELETE from products where id = ". $id;
// You can also use
// $delete = "DELETE from products where id=$id";

if (mysqli_query($db,$delete))
  {
  echo "Database updated successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "An error occurred: " . mysqli_error($db);
  }

?>
```

---

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Here are a few tutorials on prepared statements that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5%3a-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on PDO:

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

Comment: Your explanation of his process and looping over results is entirely incorrect.

Comment: Excuse me? You'll need to elaborate. I don't submit *just cuz* @DanielWilliams - I tested it with OP's code with it outside the loop and it did not work. I suggest you test it yourself without unfounded proof. The -1 is also uncalled for (from whoever downvoted it).

Comment: Your explanation of $cell['id'] is incorrect. He is looping over the columns of the row since the row is a simple array then trying to use it like associative array (that is his error). His print is also in an OK location given his assumptions. So of course it didn't work. But not for the reason you gave.

Comment: The `foreach($row as $cell)` and `$row["id"]` look again and tell me that's going to work. **AS** `$cell` @DanielWilliams --- This, related to OP's `<a href='delete.php?id=".$row["id"] ."' >Delete</a>` which when clicked on, will fail. I suggest you spend an hour like I did to thoroughly test this and compare using `<a href='delete.php?id=".$row["id"] ."' >Delete</a>` as opposed to `<a href='delete.php?id=".$cell["id"] ."' >Delete</a>`

Comment: Of course clicking delete will fail. But not for your posted reason. If you really spent an hour on this you could spend the 1 minute it takes to find your error.

Comment: That's what I don't quite understand by the reason. Where did I make a mistake in the explanation? I might not have explained it the way I meant. @DanielWilliams I'm open to your suggestions and will give credit in a comment. Anything to make this correct.

Comment: I went over my explanation and I can't see where the error is. You're going to have to point it out to me. Otherwise, I'm leaving it the way it is, downvote or not. @DanielWilliams You're more than welcome editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and precise explanation. Now, here's what happens when I put the `<a href='delete_so.php?id=".$cell["id"] ."'>Delete</a>` outside the `foreach` loop; I have 3 entries in my DB and only the last one shows the row **with the delete link** that will in fact delete it (yet, it shows the 1-2-3 ID rows too), and when it's place **"inside"** the loop, all 3 show up that are deleteable. @DanielWilliams